# I want to hide my youtube embeded code from my source code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  iframe in my website i want it to be encrypted so that user can't understand the link and when user try to paste on browser it should show the video

```
<iframe
  id="<?php echo $fetchyoutubedetails['id'];?>"
  class="yt_players"
  width="972"
  height="284"
  src="<?php echo $fetchyoutubedetails['video_links']?>?rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1;showinfo=0;"
  frameborder="0"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
>
```

Comment: **Please refer to this link. This question is similar to your question** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671780/encrypt-html-code-in-source-view

Answer (score 4):

## This does not work.

The browser has to be able to read the link, and as soon as the browser is able to do that, the user is able to do that.